# Odoo CSV import: Found multiple matches for field

Tags: csv, import, odoo, odoo-13

I am using https://github.com/tfrancoi/odoo_csv_import to import data into Odoo "res.partner" model. There is no problem importing most of the fields, but when I try to import the field state_id this error is thrown: "Found multiple matches for field 'State' (2 matches)".

```
res_partner_mapping = {
    (........ more fields here)
    'country_id/id' : mapper.const('base.es'),
    'state_id': mapper.map_val('myStateField', my_state_dictionary),
}
```

Here my_state_dictionary simply returns the state_id searched, for example "AV", "M" or "B".

The problem is that state_id is a a composed key so it should be filtered by country_id and state_id. For example, "AV" is a state in Spain, but it is also a different state in Italy, so if it is only filtered by state_id it returns 2 records.

The field is declared in Odoo this way:

```
state = fields.Many2one('country',related=city.country)
```

How can I specify the relation **`related=city.country`** to import the data with odoo_csv_import?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem and this is how I fixed it: I added the create function where I am looking for the state with my country code.

judet_id is the state ID field in my model and RO is country code.

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    state_curent = self.env['res.country.state'].search([("id","=",vals['judet_id'])])
    if(state_curent and state_curent.country_id.code != 'RO'):          
        state = self.env['res.country.state'].search([("code","=", state_curent.code), ("country_id.code","=", "RO")])
        if state:
            vals['judet_id'] = state.id
    return super().create(vals)
```

Comment: Could you explain little bit more, please? Can you copy how do you assign values to res_partner_mapping.state_id, please? Thank you